# Current "best practice" for exporting Firefox passwords

Tags: linux, firefox

I've got multiple copies and profiles of x86_64 Firefox running on Linux (Debian v10 "Buster"). At present I'm relying on screenshots for backing up saved passwords.

I see that in the past there have been recommendations of https://github.com/kspearrin/ff-password-exporter which appears attractive since the source is available for audit. However since security is a somewhat fluid field and since it would be easy for something nasty to be embedded in this type of tool: can anybody recommend current (late 2020) "best practice" for extracting passwords for backup and reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ff-password-exporter](https://github.com/kspearrin/ff-password-exporter)
is a credible product and should be trust-worthy.

Another option from a highly-regarded and credible source is
[NirSoft's PasswordFox](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html).

You may ensure that a program is not stealing your passwords by blocking it in the
Windows firewall.

Comment: I myself use "LastPass".. there are many really good products out there (FOR FREE) that are going to be better than anything you can implement on your own.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas I have absolutely no intention of attempting to implement something myself, although for something like this I'd prefer to be able to review/audit the sourcecode and compile from it myself. If you have strong recommendations please contribute them as an answer.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the confirmation. Windows Firewall is irrelevant in this case since- as stated- I'm running Linux, also there are so many ways of exfiltration data (via DNS queries, pings and so on) that I don't think it should be relied upon.